# Removing About tab in personal msteams application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a brief question - is it possibile to get rid of "About" tab in personal msteams application? I would like to have only my custom tab.

Comment: StackOverflow is probably not the right place for this question. Not sure if it helps but first result on Google was https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/remove-a-tab-in-teams-c18c875c-0738-40ec-a228-61d7eb27f745

Comment: Seem like a legit question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to remove the About tab for an app. It is by design and is used to display the basic details of the app like its functionality, terms of use and privacy policy. We do not have any plan to allow users to remove this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why all the downvotes, I think it's a valid question - perhaps people are getting confused and think you're trying to remove a "normal" tab in a channel.

I don't think it's possible to remove an application's "About" tab though - certainly I've not seen where/how to do so, and I think it needs to be there so people can easily access your privacy policy, terms, description, etc.